# YouTube Plugin is not showing player icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, youtube, icons

I am facing an issue with Firefox 44.0.2 and the YouTube embedded player. In some cases the player isn't showing the player elements and in some it does. A friend of mine told me, this is related to an issue, that the Non-SVG icons aren't loading.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the embedding? In every other browser it is working like a charm.

Comment: It's when you redirect from http to https. A fix for Firefox is in progress.

Comment: @RobertLongson you should post as an answer that using the *http**s*** url to the youtube video solves the problem. Saved me a lot of headache.. thanks

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It will cease to be an issue in the next release of Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, thanks for the heads up.